# IdentityServer v3 not returning from Authorize endpoint

Tags: c#, identityserver3

So switching machines for work from a windows 7 box to a windows 10. The main application is a set of web sites that use IdentityServer3. When I go to any of the non-authenticated pages, they load fine. But if I navigate to one that needs the user to be logged in, the page just spins. If I trigger an IIS reset, it appears the page was hung on the Authorize endpoint.

So the application works fine on the windows 7 box, so I am working on the assumption something is misconfigured on the windows 10 box. I am not seeing anything in my logs and the logs on identity server look pretty clean. Is there an easy way to debug the authorize endpoint to spot where it is hanging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bad connection string to the database. Nothing in the logs, but this what it ended up being.